# Java generics naming conventions

Tags: java, generics

According to [the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
>
> K - Key
>
> N - Number
>
> T - Type
>
> V - Value
>
> S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types

However , I have seen codes like this

```
public <R> Observable<R> compose(Transformer<? super T, ? extends R> transformer) {
        return ((Transformer<T, R>) transformer).call(this);
    }
```

Here it is using R, from what source can I find out what R means in here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Result" or "return type." The former is particularly common in the JDK 8 classes.

Consider the JavaDocs for [java.util.function.Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), for instance:

> R - the type of the result of the function

The patterns `<R>` and `, ?R>` don't appear in OpenJDK 7's classes (citation: I [downloaded the source](https://jdk7.java.net/source.html) and did a grep), but they do appear in several classes for building the Java toolchain itself, like javac. There, the R sometimes seems to [stand for "result"](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/langtools/file/5713b8d2db3f/src/share/classes/com/sun/source/tree/Tree.java#l602) and [sometimes for "return type."](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/langtools/file/5713b8d2db3f/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol.java#l1428)

Comment: Thanks for that, does that definition only exists in Java8 functional interfaces or across other versions of Java?

Comment: @WenChao Updated my answer with a bit about Java 7.

Comment: thanks for the effort! According to the link you posted, <D> seems to be another naming convention used which is not documented well. Really hope there is a clear explanation on how and when to use these namings rather than look into java source codes.

Comment: Agreed! It would be nice if Oracle updated the conventions page you referenced in your question, especially given that lambdas will probably see an increase in R type names.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. Here R stands for "return type".

If you look at "adaptor design pattern" that convert one type into another type to work with two completely different interfaces. There you can find such generic values.

If you are writing this method that transforms or calls on object of type T and returns observable object of another type then what will you use for type of returned value? There is no hard and fast rule for generic type naming. The only rule applies here is that it should be short and meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but where can I find the documentation about it?